# Leanring about checksums on apache website for netbeans

Tags: checksum

I don't know where else to ask this so here i am.

i downloaded netbeans on
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/netbeans/netbeans-installers/15/Apache-NetBeans-15-bin-windows-x64.exe  ( don't worry, the link is not to the direct download, but a page with options)

Here they say it's essential that i do a checksum or PGP check. After looking around they do explain how to calculate the checksum by : "To check a hash, you have to compute the proper checksum of the file you just downloaded ; then compare it with the published checksum of the original."

However there is no checksum published anywhere i looked? they say all keys and checksums are on the official site per release, so i checked downloads -> releases -> and clicked on various releases there but no where a checksum to be found??? There is a KEYS file with every release but nope.. no checksum there. Am i doing something wrong? according to a tutorial i found the checksum is to be displayed on the website the file has been downloaded from?

Note: i downloaded their suggested file, which is an .exe installer

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

The PGP signature can be downloaded here: https://dlcdn.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans-installers/15/Apache-NetBeans-15-bin-windows-x64.exe.asc

This is not documented anywhere, I just guessed the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

When you go onto the netbeans main download page, after selecting the version that you are downloading, the checksums are next to the download link for the file that you are downloading in brackets. [Screenshot of netbeans download page for version 15 with checksum highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLdkI.png)